# Vue router still loading previous data after changing rout

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

i have a strange behavior where i load my home page that is quite heavy in terms of images/data to load then i click on a link while its loading, it load the next component in the view (through router-link) but the previous data seem to be still loading in the background + if i push the browser back button, the url change but the previous view don't load untill previous data finished to load then it load.

My code is quite complexe now so i'm not sure which part to share here but is it something common like im missing a destroy() method or so ?

Happens only on first load, after once data are cached it work all fine.

Comment: i think you should fetch all the data before allowing any interation on page

Comment: if you are using Axios - you can use a CancelToken to cancel AJAX requests in the `beforeDestroy()` hook of the component.

Comment: Thank you i will check that, but it feel it more like all the images still charging because my fetch are done at this point, will check more, probably something not finish to load i guess you are right.